# complexity of using Extended Euclid for multivariate gcd computations

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

part of exercise 31.2-7 of CLRS states

> show how to find integers x0, x1...xn such that gcd(a0, a1...an) = a0x0 + a1x1..an xn. Show that the number of divisions performed by your algorithm is O(n + lg(max{a0, a1...an})

I cannot figure out where that complexity expression possibly comes from.

An algorithm that comes to mind can be found in the Wikipedia page for Extended Euclid, under the section "The case of more than two numbers". In particular, we have gcd(a0, a1...an) = gcd(a0, gcd(a1...gcd(a_n-1, an)))...). Hence, repeatedly apply two-variable Extended euclid to get the coefficients of all n+1 arguments. Each call to two-variable Extended Euclid takes O(lg(b)) divisions, where b is the smaller of two arguments.

Hence, an upper bound to this is O(n * lg(max{a0, a1...an}): n calls to two-variable extended Euclid, each taking at most lg(max{a0, a1...an}) recursive steps. So where in the world can one possibly get an n *plus* lg(max{a0, a1...an} runtime? Is it because in the calls to Extended Euclid, whatever value of b, the smaller of the two, decays extremely rapidly so that b is basically O(1) for most of the calls?

Also, interestingly, Knuth TAOCP volume 2, in section 4.5.3 (page 364) problem 45 gives this as a problem:

> Develop the analysis of algorithms for computing the greatest common divisor of three or more integers.

The problem has difficulty rating "HM48" (where HM means "requires higher level mathematics not discussed in the book, and 48 is a score out of 50, where 50 is on the level of something like "prove Fermat's last theorem").

Answer (score 0):

My reasoning for the O(n * lg max{a0...an} ) is incorrect. Even though we are calling two-variable Extended euclid n times, the smaller argument b in all of these calls in fact is strictly decreasing, even across different calls of Extended euclid; *not* reset every time to some top-level value aj as I had originally assumed.

Hence, the two terms in the complexity, n + lg max{a0...an} dominate in different regimes; the n term is for large n, and the lg max{a0...an} is for small n and large a0, a1.